# Can't install APK from eclipse on my HTC SENSATION

Tags: android, eclipse

While i'm trying to run my app that's what i get in the console:

```
[2013-02-05 18:03:46 - IncomingCallBC] Android Launch!
[2013-02-05 18:03:46 - IncomingCallBC] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-05 18:03:46 - IncomingCallBC] Performing com.example.incomingcallbc.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-02-05 18:03:46 - IncomingCallBC] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'SH18RT500393'
[2013-02-05 18:03:46 - IncomingCallBC] Uploading IncomingCallBC.apk onto device 'SH18RT500393'
[2013-02-05 18:03:47 - IncomingCallBC] Installing IncomingCallBC.apk...
[2013-02-05 18:03:47 - IncomingCallBC] Success!
[2013-02-05 18:03:47 - IncomingCallBC] Starting activity com.example.incomingcallbc.MainActivity on device SH18RT500393
```

However, the apk wasn't installed on my device. In the first run it's installing correctly, but after some changes in the code and running again, it doesn't install/reinstall the apk. even if i'm deleting the app manually from the device and trying to run it doesn't really install it.

Is it HTC SENSATION common issue ? or some false setting of my eclipse?

thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't suppose your LogCat has any errors?

Comment: nop...it doesn't really install the app on the device so the LogCat is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform following things:

> [1] Clean and Rebuild your project from eclipse.
>
> [2] Unplug and restart your device and plug it again.
>
> **[3] Windows > Preference > Android > DDMS > ADB Connection time out
>   (ms):**
>
> You will see **5000** there change that to **10000**.

Then try to run application again from eclipse.

Comment: Restarting the device always helps. after restarting the first running installs the app correctly. but it happens again when i'm editing the code and running again from eclipse.

I can't restart my device everytime i want to run the app after changing some code...it's not reasonable to do it..

Comment: Ohk then try to change time out from your DDMS settings. That might solve your problem.

Comment: can you please guide me how to do it?

Comment: Didn't help.
also restart eclipse, unpluged & plug cable again. Right now, only restarting the device can solve it :(

Comment: @UdiOshi is your logcat showing any errors at that point of time?

Comment: 02-05 18:32:21.818: W/dalvikvm(10397): CreateJavaVM failed: dvmGcStartup failed
02-05 18:32:21.818: E/AndroidRuntime(10397): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
02-05 18:32:22.259: W/dalvikvm(10404): CreateJavaVM failed: dvmGcStartup failed
02-05 18:32:22.259: E/AndroidRuntime(10404): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
02-05 18:32:22.619: W/dalvikvm(10415): CreateJavaVM failed: dvmGcStartup failed
02-05 18:32:22.619: E/AndroidRuntime(10415): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed

Comment: USB debug is checked in the device, and also allowed install application not from play

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23975/discussion-between-udi-oshi-and-pratik-sharma)

Comment: @UdiOshi did you apply your device software update in recent period?